# Как получить и использовать значение XML-узла Version в CSPROJ-файле?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, msbuild

Имеется проект библиотеки .netstandard 2.0, которая используется внутри компании и распостраняется как NuGet-пакет из локального хранилища. Для этого в свойствах проекта, на вкладке "Пакет", выбран чекбокс "Создать пакет NuGet при сборке", а в CSPROJ-файл добавлено выполнение команды после сборки NuGet-пакета. CSPROJ-файл выглядит следующим образом:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- ... -->
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.18332</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.18332</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>C:\Full\Path\To\My.Namespace.PackageId\My.Namespace.PackageId.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>C:\Full\Path\To\My.Namespace.PackageId\My.Namespace.PackageId.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="nuget add .\bin\Release\$(TargetName).1.0.0.nupkg -Source \\net\share\packages" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Как видно, свойство Version должно использоваться для составления имени nupkg-файла, но как его получить и использовать в Exec Command?

---

#### UPDATE

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000692/3129992) нашёл пример использования AssemblyVersion, который не могу адаптировать для Version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для получения версии пакета можно использовать `$(PackageVersion)`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- ... -->
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.18332</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.18332</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>My.Namespace.PackageId.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- нужно включить создание пакета NuGet при сборке 
       в свойствах проекта на вкладке "Пакет" -->
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="nuget add .\bin\Release\$(TargetName).$(PackageVersion).nupkg -Source \\net\share\packages" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Replacement tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens)
- [NuGet CLI reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)